# nginx- duplicate default server error

Tags: nginx

In my error log i get

> [emerg] 10619#0: a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.com:4

on Line 4 I have:

```
server_name mysite.com   www.mysite.com;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post your full config. Each `server {}` should have its own `listen` directive.

Comment: If you were editing something in sites-enabled and the connection closed unexpectedly, you may end with an auto save file there from the text editor, so you will end with almost all configurations duplicated, just delete that file (for nano file.save)

Answer (score 282, accepted):

You likely have other files (such as the `default` configuration) located in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` that needs to be removed.

This issue is caused by a repeat of the `default_server` parameter supplied to one or more `listen` directives in your files.  You'll likely find this conflicting directive reads something similar to:

```
listen 80 default_server;
```

As the [nginx core module documentation for `listen`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) states:

> The `default_server` parameter, if present, will cause the server to become the default server for the specified `address:port` pair. If none of the directives have the `default_server` parameter then the first server with the `address:port` pair will be the default server for this pair.

This means that there must be another file or `server` block defined in your configuration with `default_server` set for port 80.  nginx is encountering that first before your `mysite.com` file so try removing or adjusting that other configuration.

If you are struggling to find where these directives and parameters are set, try a search like so:

```
grep -R default_server /etc/nginx
```

Comment: Just to be clear it is the `default_server` keyword that can only appear in one config - you can have multiple sites defined with `listen 80;`

Comment: Thanks, you are helped me. In my case I found an dublicate into /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save

Comment: Further to @Eborbob's comment, the `default_server` parameter can only appear once for each `address:port` pair.  This means it is possible (and common) to have `default_server` present multiple times in a overall nginx configuration, but applying to different IPs/ports.

Comment: You may find a duplicated copy of your config file (e.g. the default file is duplicated regarding the server crash as  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#default# ).
you should move it to somewhere else to test by "nginx -t".

Answer (score 20):

OS Debian 10 + nginx.
In my case, I unlinked the "default" page as:

1. `cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`
2. `unlink default`
3. `service nginx restart`

Comment: This will work, but then you won't have a default server.

Answer (score 13):

Execute this at the terminal to see conflicting configurations listening to the same port:

```
grep -R default_server /etc/nginx
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're on Digital Ocean this means you need to go to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ and then REMOVE using rm -R digitalocean and default

It fixed it for me!

[Pic of Console on Windows 10 using Bitvise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhntr.png)

Comment: This was the simple answer that worked for me. I had to go to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ and ```rm -R previousServerFolderName``` then do ```sudo service nginx restart``` to make ```systemctl status nginx``` show "active (running)"

Answer (score 5):

In my case, commenting out the wildcard directive on `include` in the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` worked

```
#include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/abcdef.com;
```

PS: as per the comments above, this could be a solution if there is just one configuration (either default or your custom one)

Answer (score 2):

In my case junk files from editor caused the problem.
I had a config as below:

```
#...
http {
 # ...
 include ../sites/*;
}
```

In the `../sites` directory initially I had a `default.config` file.
However, by mistake I saved duplicate files as `default.config.save`  and `default.config.save.1`.
Removing them resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I my case, I already have a file inside the sites-enabled.

And the issue had resolved after removing the unwanted and swap related files.

Options to try the nginx configuration is ok or not by the command

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Result:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Answer (score 0):

If davidjb's answer does not show multiple default_server lines, check for multiple include directives.

It is possible you accidentally included your default (or another site) twice.