# site not enabling ssl after auto configuration by Certbot

Tags: ssl, nginx, deployment, ssl-certificate, devops

We have a static site code and want to have ssl enabled on it. This server has other few static sites running as well. Here is what I have in configurations

```
server {
  root /home/ubuntu/projects/example-beta/dist;
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name  beta.example.com;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;  
  }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/beta.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/beta.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = beta.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



  server_name  beta.example.com;


    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

But it doesnt pick ssl. I have replaced actual domain name with `example`. its been few days I have been trying different solutions. Sorry I am newbie in devOps. Any workaround or help is really appreciated

**Edit**

current configs

```
server {
  root /home/ubuntu/projects/savepakistan-beta/dist;
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name  beta.wesavepakistan.com;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;  
  }

  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/beta.wesavepakistan.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/beta.wesavepakistan.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name beta.wesavepakistan.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Well, what happens? Doe the site work just with HTTP not HTTPS? Does it return for 404? Did you do `nginx -t` to see if there were any issues with your config? Did you restart or reload `nginx` after the changes were made?

Comment: yes I did *nginx -t* and there was no error but the site just wont load after restarting nginx

Comment: @ShawnC. I can only think of permission issue. Well sll these certificates are only accessible via `sudo`

Comment: Does the error log say anything

Comment: It doesnt say anything. I have tried many configs eg https://tecadmin.net/nginx-force-redirect-to-https-with-www/ but still no success. redirect works but it just doesnt do anything on https

Comment: @ShawnC. if there are some nginx error log when it tired to fetch that https url, I am not aware of. Please let me know if such logs exist I will look straight away

Comment: @ShawnC. I tried to show content by doing `cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/beta.wesavepakistan.com/privkey.pem` but got permission issue. but when I do `sudo cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/beta.wesavepakistan.com/privkey.pem` it works. I am not sure if nginx is able to access these certificates and is actually the issue

Comment: I found below logs
`$ tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log`
2019/08/09 10:17:53 [alert] 6691#6691: *17 open socket #3 left in connection 5
2019/08/09 10:17:53 [alert] 6691#6691: aborting

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the second server block is intendent to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS, I would substitute this block with the following:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name beta.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

In order to fix SSL issues I would do:

- Ensure that your certificate is created using hostname: `beta.example.com`
- move out all the ssl directives (`listen 443 ssl; ssl_certificate ...; etc`) from the `location` block and put them under `server` block.

Comment: as I have multiple static sites and other small servers. I got following error
    sudo nginx -t
  nginx: [emerg] a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/abcxyz.com:2
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: See this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973774/nginx-duplicate-default-server-error
You should have only one default server.

Comment: Even after having one default server doesnt solve this issue. site still wont load. Please note firewall is disabled. So there shouldnt be any issue from firewal side

Comment: Did you changed also the second block with the suggestion?

Comment: https://beta.wesavepakistan.com/ site in case you need to visit and check it for yourself. Thank you much for help

Comment: @Tanweer it seems that there is no service that is resolving the request.
Anyway the redirect from HTTP to HTTPS is correctly working

Comment: Yes redirect is working correctly but ssl seems to have issue. Ssl certification was auto generated by certbot

Comment: @Tanweer can you update the post with your current configuration?

Comment: Actually currently I am away from my laptop. I have exactly same configuration with second block changed as per your instructions. But I will also update with exact current configurations soon

Comment: I have added current configs at end of question in `Edit` section. Please have a look

Comment: I also confirmed the files and certificates exists on specified paths

Comment: I can only think of permission issue. Well sll these certificates are only accessible via `sudo`

Comment: Can be possible, the default user/group for nginx should be ```www-data```, maybe you could try to ```sudo chown www-data:www-data /etc/letsencrypt/live/beta.example.com/fullchain.pem``` and ```sudo chown www-data:www-data /etc/letsencrypt/live/beta.example.com/privkey.pem```
I am not sure this will fix anyway

Comment: it didnt fix anything. (Please check my comments on Question. There are some useful comments)

Answer (score 0):

To everyone visiting this question

Fix was: In UFW(if enabled), you have to enable FULL nginx and Ports(for HTTPs) in AWS EC2(in my case, yours can be different)