# SSL certificate generation on an EC2 machine with NGINX

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I am trying to generate an ssl certificate on an AWS EC2 nano machine configured with a NGINX server.
My NGINX configuration file is as follows:
`server {`     
   `listen 80 default_server;`    
   `listen [::]:80 default_server;`    
   `root /var/www/html;`    
   `server_name my_server_name.com;`
`}`
When I check my Nginx configuration with the following command :
`nginx -t`
this error is returned:
`nginx: [emerg] a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:22 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Of course, when I try to go further in generating the SSL certificate with the following command:
`certbot certonly --dry-run`
the following error is returned:
`Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t.`

What changes/commands do I need to make to generate the SSL certificate ?

I have modified my Nginx configuration file in a thousand ways, without success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973774/nginx-duplicate-default-server-error

Comment: The issue `duplicate default server` is caused by a repeat of the `default_server` parameter .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed NGINX correctly on your machine, for Certbot to take into account your configuration, you must first move (or delete) the default one located here:

- `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

for this, you will need these 2 commands:

- `cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`
- `rm default`

Once these 2 commands are done, you have to switch off the NGINX server to generate the SSL certificate, using this command:

- `service nginx stop`

Now you can restart your command and generate the SSL certificate with :

- `certbot certonly`